# Hibernate - Mapping subclass POJO to same table as its parent

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

In our code have something along the lines of these two Java classes:

```
public class MailMessage {
    private String id;
    private String message;
    private String sentTime;

    // getters and setters
}

public class MailMessageWithRecipients extends MailMessage {
    private String recipients;

    // getter and setter for recipients
}
```

The purpose of separating the recipients list is that, since it can be very large, we would like to avoid loading it when possible. We would like to be able to map both MailMessage and MailMessageWithRecipients to a single table; `mail_messages`. However, if I try to do this in our Hibernate mapping file -

```
<class name="MailMessage" table="mail_messages" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="id" column="message_id" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid" />
    </id>
    <property name="message" column="message" />
    <property name="sentTime" column="sentTime" />
</class>

<class name="MailMessageWithRecipients" table="mail_messages" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="id" column="message_id" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid" />
    </id>
    <property name="message" column="message" />
    <property name="sentTime" column="sentTime" />
    <property name="recipients">
        <column name="recipients" sql-type="longblob" />
    </property>
</class>
```

And then write a query something like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from MailMessage where id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", id);
MailMessage message = query.uniqueResult();
```

I get a "*org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result*" exception when the query is executed, even when there is only a single row in the mail_messages table. I suspect this is because it sees that row as being both a MailMessage and a MailMessageWithRecipients. Is there a way to map these two objects to the same table this way while maintaining the parent-child Java relationship? Related discussions I've seen recommend a component relationship in the mapping file, but it seems to me that that would involve removing the inheritance structure and turning MailMessageWithRecipients into a facade structure for MailMessage. If that's the only way this can be done, I'll do it, but I was wondering if there was a mapping that allows the inheritance structure to remain intact, as that would involve significantly less refactoring of our code.

Comment: I don't see the parent-child relationship in the system you're building. Isn't a mail message without recipients still just a mail message with a blank recipients field, and isn't a mail message with recipients just a mail message with data in the recipients field?  Regardless, if there is really an inheritance hierarchy, you can use one of the available Hibernate inheritance strategies listed here: I think you'll want to focus on the one table strategy https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3306

Comment: We want to be able to use the MailMessage object to reference all the data in the mail_message table excluding the recipients field, as that field is large and costly to deal with. We would like to be able to use MailMessageWithRecipients to access that data in some methods that we also use with MailMessage, so as to avoid duplicating code. Also, I should have mentioned that we are not on Hibernate 4 - we're on 3.3.2. It does not seem that the @Inheritance annotation is available in our version.